# How to get rid of charset on response header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, header, response

I am trying to make a file download controller, but unfortunately rails seems to be hell bent on not letting me remove charset from header

Content-Type: application/x-octet-stream; charset=utf-8

I have tried after_filter, headers['Content-Type'], response.headers['Content-Type'], etc but no avail. UTF-8 just keeps coming up. Any ideas why it happens and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

Just found an alternative way to perform this:

```
head :ok, :content_type => @media.mime_type, 
 :content_disposition => "attachment;filename=#{@media.filename}", 
 :x_sendfile => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/data/#{@media.physname}", 
 :content_transfer_encoding => 'binary'
```

If Content-Transfer-Encoding is set to binary, the charset is no longer added. Found this after excavating the source a bit.